# Jekyll not serving my homepage

Tags: debian

Whenever I try to start jekyll on debian with `jekyll serve --host example.org` it tells me I need to prepend `bundle exec`. When I do `bundle exec jekyll serve --host example.org` it gives me this:

```
Configuration file: /home/max/grunzwanzling/_config.yml
Configuration file: /home/max/grunzwanzling/_config.yml
            Source: /home/max/grunzwanzling
       Destination: /home/max/grunzwanzling/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
                    done in 0.266 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/max/grunzwanzling'
Configuration file: /home/max/grunzwanzling/_config.yml
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

It has worked before but I tried to install postfix in the meantime which has not worked very well. Could this have affected jekyll in any way?

Answer (score 0):

An error message:

> getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

is typically a DNS issue.

Either one or more of the hostnames you're using is not configured in DNS or your DNS is broken. Check with `dig` or `nslookup` if a known host such as `serverfault.com` resolves and if `example.com` and the others in your config work to determine if DNS is completely broken or you just need fix a typo in your config, edit your `/etc/hosts` or amend the DNS records for your domain.

Comment: I added my Ip and my hostname to 'etc/hosts' and it seems to work. But now i get '[2016-12-05 17:12:21] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00▒\x01\x00\x00▒\x03\x03▒l\x7F^\x7F▒▒\x12֒@▒q7Z▒▒* q▒▒▒▒▒\x0F▒Vߪ\x00\x00"▒+▒/▒,▒0̨̩▒\x14▒\x13▒\t▒\x13▒'.
[2016-12-05 17:12:21] ERROR bad URI `▒\x13▒'.' as soon as I try to access the page via Google Chrome

Comment: OK, fixed it. I just needed to delete my cookies. But will my entry in '/etc/hosts' cause any problems later?

Comment: That depends on which entry you added but usually not

Comment: I added my ip with my hostname. I mean, this is only a workaround right? I have not really fixed the core issue. Will this cause any other problems in the future?